# Does reusing Window with different usercontrols break MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I've got a quick question regarding the MVVM pattern.
I'd like to create a window with the style of the company (background color, company logo,...) for quick content showing. This way I can just replace the content (usercontrol) of the window and keep the same look as used throughout the application.
The window will be used for an about window, error message window, settings window,...
To avoid copy/pasting code I want to reuse the same window and when creating the usercontrol, link it to show using that window. Now my question is if this can be implemented without breaking the MVVM design pattern.

Thank you for your help

Ben

Comment: yes it can be implemented without breaking the MVVM design pattern

Comment: You can create your window with a grid for content and use the same window for each screen just adding the required content to the grid

Comment: This sounds like it would be better done with a content control and data templates

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reusing the same window instance, you could create a custom window *template* and apply this one to any window instance you want: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/.

Since your question seems to purely view-related, it isn't really about MVVM. Both a `Window` and a `UserControl` are views.